# Python Multiprocessing: Child processes working at different speed

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I'm new to `python multiprocessing`. I'm trying to use a `third-party web-API` to fetch data for multiple symbols of interest. Here is my python code:

```
<!-- language:lang-py-->

def my_worker(symbol, table_name):
    while True:
        # Real-time data for the symbol, third party code which is verified
        data = webApi.getData(symbol)
        query = ('insert into ' + table_name + '(var1, var2) values("%s, %s")' %(data[0], data[1]))
        # Execute query and store the data. Omitted for sake of brevity

if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_symbols = get_symbols_list() # List of symbols
    my_tables = get_tables_list()   # Corresponding list of mysql tables
    jobs = []
    for pidx in range(len(my_symbols)):
        pname = 'datarecorder_' + my_symbols[pidx]  # Naming the process for later identification
        p = multiprocessing.Process(name=pname, target=my_worker, args=(my_symbols[pidx], my_tables[pidx],))
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()
```

There are approximately `50 processes created` in this code.

**Problem that I'm facing:** *is that when I look into the corresponding tables after a certain amount of time (say 5 minutes), the number of records in each of the table in my_tables is drastically different (on the order of multiple of 10s)*

Since I am using the same API, the same network connection and the same code to fetch and write data to the mysql tables, I'm not sure what is causing this difference in number of records. `My hunch is that each of the 50 processes is getting assigned an unequal amount of RAM and other resources, and perhaps the priority is also different(?)`

Can someone tell me how can I ensure that each of these processes poll the webApi roughly equal number of times?

Comment: _on the order of multiple of 10s_

Do you mean that some tables have 50 more records in them, or that some tables have 50 _times_ as many records as others? Scheduling isn't deterministic\*, so you can't and therefore also shouldn't depend on it behaving in any particular way. Fairness is the goal, but there's no guarantee for it in real time scheduling.

\* For useful definitions of deterministic.

Comment: I mean that after 5 minutes some tables will have 10-20 records while other might have 200-300 records. If fairness is the goal the number of records in these tables should be more or less equal and a couple of records more or less won't hurt me, but this order of difference is too critical to ignore.

Comment: To me it seems you would be better off with using [multiprocessing.Pool](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool) (eg apply_async or map) instead of creating all the Processes directly as creating new Processes takes some time - maybe that is the reason for the timing problem

Comment: @janbrohl, if your hypothesis is correct, then if I let this code run for a long enough interval (say half an hour), then the number of records in each of the tables should asymptotically converge? I'm gonna try this out, and see if that works.

Comment: Which OS?  Python has no say in how the OS decides to schedule processes, so the OS may be key.  You'll need to use OS-specific tools to answer questions like how much each RAM each process has, and the priority of each.  About using `Pool`, that would be more _natural_, but doubt it matters:  while processes are "heavier" than threads, there's no OS under which process creation time is significant compared to "5 minutes".

Comment: BTW, do you have enough total RAM for 50 of these processes to run simultaneously?  If you don't, and the OS has to page RAM to/from disk, orders-of-magnitude differences will be routine and unavoidable.

Comment: The main reason why to use multiprocessing is for using multiple cores for faster computations for most situations touching networking threads are a better choice - try to use [multiprocessing.dummy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.dummy) (which uses threads but apart from that is the same as multiprocessing) instead of multiprocessing to see if it gets better.

Comment: Currently this code is running on windows, but ultimately it will run on a linux web server. I can try multiprocessing.dummy too. Will post results soon.

Comment: Actually using a Pool doesnt help with functions containing infinite loops as not all scheduled tasks are executed at the same time (only as many as you have CPUs by default) - only switching tasks when they are finished

Comment: If you store your data in a single file/variable, you MAY have issues with concurrency access. Check http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/01/04/shared-counter-with-pythons-multiprocessing to see if it could be your issue

Answer (score 0):

An effective way to approach such things is to start with something vastly simpler, then *add* stuff to it until "a problem" shows up.  Otherwise it's just blind guesswork.

For example, here's something much simpler, which I'm running under Windows (like you - I'm using a current Win10 Pro) and Python 3.5.2:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from time import sleep

NPROCS = 50

def worker(i, d):
    while True:
        d[i] += 1
        sleep(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    d = mp.Manager().dict()
    for i in range(NPROCS):
        d[i] = 0

    ps = []
    for i in range(NPROCS):
        p = mp.Process(target=worker, args=(i, d))
        ps.append(p)
        p.start()

    while True:
        sleep(3)
        print(d.values())
```

Here's the most recent output after about a minute of running:

```
[67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67,
 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 66,
 66, 66, 66, 66, 66, 66, 66, 66, 66, 66,
 66, 66, 66, 66, 66, 66, 66, 66, 66, 66,
 66, 66, 66, 66, 66, 66, 66, 66, 66, 66]
```

So I can conclude that there's nothing "inherently unfair" about process scheduling on this box.  On your box?  Run it and see ;-)

I can also see in Task Manager that all 50 processes are treated similarly, with (for example) the same RAM usage and priority.  FYI, this box happens to have 8 logical cores (4 physical), and way more than enough RAM (16GB).

Now there are worlds of additional complications in what you're doing, none of which we can guess from here.  For example, maybe you're running out of RAM and so some processes are greatly delayed by pagefile swapping.  Or maybe the work you're doing takes much longer for some arguments than others.  Or ... but, regardless, the simplest way to find out is to incrementally make a very simple program a little fancier at a time.